# pthread_create interception on Linux Kernel 6.1

Tags: c, linux-kernel, pthreads, interceptor, ld-preload

I'm trying to intercept calls to the pthread library using LD_PRELOAD.

I successfully intercept all calls (ex `pthread_mutex_init`, `pthread_mutex_lock`) except `pthread_create`. I don't get any error, the interception simply does not occur.

My code works on kernel 5.10 (glibc 2.31) but once on kernel 6.1 (glibc 2.36) it does not anymore. However I need kernel 6.1 for other things in the code so downgrading is not an option.

Has anything changed regarding the pthread_create function between kernels 5.10 and 6.1 (or glibc 2.31 and 2.36)?

My code: compiled as a shared library and then loaded using LD_PRELOAD.

```
#ifndef _GNU_SOURCE
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#endif
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int pthread_create(pthread_t *thread, const pthread_attr_t *attr,
                   void *(*start_routine)(void *), void *arg) {

    printf("[p] pthread_create\n");
    return 0
}

int pthread_mutex_init(pthread_mutex_t *mutex,
                       const pthread_mutexattr_t *attr) {
                        
    printf("[p] pthread_mutex_init\n");
    return 0
}
```

`[p] pthread_mutex_init` shows up but not `[p] pthread_create`.

Note: I know for a fact that `pthread_create` is used by the intercepted binary. Using the same code and same binary with kernel 5.10 `[p] pthread_create` gets printed out.

Comment: The kernel is irrelevant as this would be a glibc thing

Comment: Perhaps you could compile (link) with `-Wl,--wrap=pthread_create` and then implement `__wrap_pthread_create`?

Comment: What is `DEBUG_PTHREAD`?  Also, your posted `pthread_create()` implementation can easily create problems - it returns `0`, indicating success, but doesn't do anything.  It doesn't start the thread, nor does it set the `pthread_t` thread ID passed from the caller to any value - which means the calling thread will likely invoke UB if it tries to use what's likely an uninitialized value.

Comment: @user253751 Yes probably I was just describing what I found out. I am using glibc 2.36 on 6.1 and glibc 2.31 on 5.10.

Comment: @TedLyngmo But pthread_create is not an undefined reference. If I recall correctly, --wrap wants an undefined symbol that will be resolved to _wwrap_*something*.

Comment: @AndrewHenle DEBUG_PTHREAD is a simple printf with a #ifdef. In this case this could simply be replaced by printf. Yes I know the implementation is not right in this case. In the "real" code I call another function and return its value. Here I only posted the code I used to confirm pthread_create was not intercepted while pthread_mutex_init was.

Comment: Try `__pthread_create_2_1`  and `__pthread_create_2_0`. `or glibc 2.31 and 2.36)?` Och yes, there is now empty libpthread library https://developers.redhat.com/articles/2021/12/17/why-glibc-234-removed-libpthread

Comment: @KamilCuk I don't seem to be able to intercept `__pthread_create_2_1` or `__pthread_create_2_0`. Same as with `pthread_create` nothing happens. Thanks for the link! I did not know about the removal of libpthread.

Comment: @VictorLft You can use `--wrap` to rename the real function into `__real_function` and then you implement `__wrap_function`. However, I tried to get that working with `pthread_create` and failed. It was some time since I did a similar thing though so I may have messed up somehow.

Comment: @TedLyngmo I cannot get it working either with `pthread_create`.

Comment: 1. As others have said, the kernel version has nothing to do with the problem.
2. This didn't reproduce using Fedora 37 (`GNU C Library (GNU libc) stable release version 2.36`).
3. It is _incredibly_ bad idea to call `printf` from within `pthread_create` interposer.
4. The code you posted doesn't compile. Please show the _actual_ code you are using.